# How does Rust implement await keyword?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

As far as I know, Rust's `await` called on a future seems to call the poll method of the future. However, the poll method needs a context parameter, if I manually call the poll method on a future, I need an executor to produce a context so a waker can be produced to call wake() on. But how the compiler knows how to get a context?

Comment: [Await](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/await-expr.html) expressions are legal only within an [async context](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html#async-context), you can consider async context as one big `Future` which will be polled by executor via `Context`, and that is the `Context` which will be used in inner(combined) futures.

Answer (score 4):

Since `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions (or blocks), you already have a context. It is hidden from you, but the compiler can access it.

If you're interested in the exact way this works, you can inspect the HIR. A function like that:

```rust
async fn bar() {
    foo().await;
}
```

Generates something like the following (you can choose "Show HIR" in the playground):

```rust
fn bar() -> impl Future {
    std::future::from_generator(move |mut _task_context| {
        let _t = {
            match std::future::IntoFuture::into_future(foo()) {
                mut __awaitee => loop {
                    match unsafe {
                        std::future::Future::poll(
                            std::pin::Pin::new_unchecked(&mut __awaitee),
                            std::future::get_context(_task_context),
                        )
                    } {
                        std::task::Poll::Ready { 0: result } => break result,
                        std::task::Poll::Pending {} => {}
                    }
                    _task_context = (yield ());
                },
            };
        };
        _t
    })
}
```

You can see the compiler uses the hidden `_task_context` parameter.

The code in the compiler that is responsible for `await` lowering can be found [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/25bb1c13bd472b75ceebee3b8dcf4dcbc431a8be/compiler/rustc_ast_lowering/src/expr.rs#L644-L838).

Comment: thanks, I think I just didn't know that async fn also holds a context.

Comment: @LunarEclipse Async function is just a function returning a future, and this future has a context like any other future.